# How to scale concurrent ETL tasks up to an arbitrary number in SSIS?

Tags: concurrency, ssis, scale, etl

## Problem (See Context below)

How can I scale individual tasks (e.g. downloading and parsing) to an arbitrary number of concurrent executions (e.g. 500) in SSIS?

## Setup Description

Our setup is that we have a list of feed urls we want to visit, get all items and insert them into the database.

Currently a php script downloads them concurrently, parses them sequentially and dumps them into csv which are later on inserted into the database using load data infile. ETL packages can handle one way or another all steps above.

Comment: The Control Flow level of SSIS allows for parallelization. I don't remember the formula but it's documented. So, out of the box you can run N concurrent tasks. If you need more parallelization, then you can either go a Script Task approach and essentially write all of your parallelization logic in code. Or you can simply run more SSIS packages in their own process. The latter approach is outlined in [We loaded 1 TB in 30 min](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537533%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Comment: @billinkc thanks that's the way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is controlled by the Package Property: MaxConcurrentExecutables.  The default is -1 which means machine cores x 2, and usually works well.

You can also affect this by setting EngineThreads on each Data Flow Task.

Here's a good summary: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlperf/archive/2007/05/11/implement-parallel-execution-in-ssis.aspx

Comment: this is the solution i was looking forward with the addition that i need to handle the splitting of work in a coordinated manner. thanks

Comment: The SSIS Control Flow designer gives you precedence constraints (arrows) and sequence containers (boxes) to manage coordination.  I try to leave this as loose as possible to maximize parallelism.  I'm not happy until the server is getting thrashed!